# Incline plane question with both static and kinetic friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction

A box of mass m = 2.5 kg is released from rest near the top of the incline. The angle of the incline is 35 degrees above the horizontal. The coefficients of static and kinetic friction between the box and the incline are u_s = 0.20 and u_k = 0.15, respectively. What will be the magnitude of the frictional force on the box once it is released?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I assumed that when the box is released, the box is moving so I only used the coefficient of kinetic friction to calculate the frictional force. So I got 3N as the frictional force but I am probably wrong because there must be a reason why they gave us the coefficient of static friction as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to find the frictional force, you must first decide whether the block will be able to slide down (check if the normal force multiplied by the co-efficient of static friction is less than the force of gravity acting parallel to the incline (mgsin(theta)). When I did it, the parallel force of gravity was around 14N, while the force of static friction was 4N. Now, we can establish that the block slides down the hill. All we have to do now is multiply the normal force by the co-efficient of kinetic friction, which gives us approximately 3N

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please don't answer "do my homework for me" type questions. This isn't a homework help site and answering them only encourages more of these types of questions that we don't want.